# A tool to run WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly

Wasm is - apparently - everywhere. I even saw some x86 based Wasm-only VMs as well, and this is very exciting! Unfortunately, it didn't build on my Mac - too bad.

The reason I looked into this is very simple: I can easily compile something - be it C++, Rust, Go or something else - and get a Wasm binary out of it, containing instructions for `wasm32-unknown-unknown`. So far, so good. But how do I run those?

With Emscripten, I can have it generate me a JS wrapper, which is very good and definitively useful. But what if I just want to target Wasm directly and have a simple `int main(void)` inside it that I'd like to run? It looks like that each Wasm file almost *needs* to have a JS wrapper in order to be executed properly.

Is there even a way to "just run" a Wasm file?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that a lot of use of wasm today is within the context of JS.  However there are several efforts to run wasm outside JS.  Two that I know of are:

- https://github.com/CraneStation/wasmtime
- https://github.com/wasmerio/wasmer

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check out LifeVM:
https://github.com/perlin-network/life

You can run a wasm program like this:

```
./life -entry 'method' /path/to/your/wasm/program.wasm [param,...]
```

However keep in mind that this is a VM only, all the "platform/environment" APIs (IO/Graphics/Networking/etc..) have to be developed or somehow provided. This is why Wasm is very convenient to use in the context of JS: there is Web APIs for a lot of use cases.

My advice: If you just want to dabble with Wasm and learn, just use Emscripten/Web and stop worrying :) Once you'll feel proficient with it, maybe that will be good time to go to look at the lower level VM side (API-less world)